# windows phone 8 OnTouchFrameReported method fires on every screen once initialized

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am a complete beginner in C# so please be gentle if it's a stupid problem :D

I have created OnTouchFrameReported method on one frame but function fires on every screen i go from there have i done something wrong ???

I can handle this problem by checking witch frame is on... but problem is now in emulator after this method is fired and i leave the frame my button clicks and other metods take 3-4s to fire... i culd use your help here guys i am realy stuck :D

XAML is irrelevant in this case and code-behind

```
 void OnTouchFrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs args)        
        {
            try
            {
                this.SetCrop(args.GetTouchPoints(this.SourceImg));
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem recently. What I did was remove the method from Touch.FrameReported whenever I was not dealing with the frame I wanted simply by doing:

```
Touch.FrameReported -= OnTouchFrameReported;
```

I know you don't want to involve XAML but I created a mouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp event for the control I was working with and added and removed the touch frame reported method respectively.

**XAML**

```
<Image MouseLeftButtonDown="mouseDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="mouseUp"/>
```

**Code**

```
public void mouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs m)
{
  Touch.FrameReported += OnTouchFrameReported;
}

public void mouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs m)
{
  Touch.FrameReported -= OnTouchFrameReported;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, you sir are a life saver, thx a bunch it resolved my problem compleatly